# Rails2 - uninitialized constant My::User::ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class included in a plugin which contains the following line

user.rb

```
class My::User < My::AbstractModel
  delegate :message_t, :to => ApplicationHelper

  #omited
end
```

So I need to call in this model the *'message_t'* function defined in the application_helper.rb,

However, Jenkins fails testing it giving the error *'uninitialized constant My::User::ApplicationHelper'* so I suppose the user model is loaded before the application_helper.rb. How can I fix it? Is there an other way to call *'message_t'* or could I change the files loading order and should I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the rails helpers from the model layer.  Helpers are designed to assist in presentation and are used by the view (and sometimes controller) layer.

Also, `delegate` is meant to be used to transfer messages to directly associated models - not to an arbitrary class.

I would recommend moving the `message_t` method out of ApplicationHelper into some library file that your model can require.  Then use a proxy object to call it instead of using `delegate`.  Or you can associate a proxy object for this purpose and use `delegate` if you like the sound of it :)

Comment: The application is actually working fine. Only Jenkins seems to have problem with it. I will give a try to your first advice, moving out message_t and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can `require 'application_helper'` in your model. It'll make sure application_helper will be loaded before your model.